# How to draw oriented edges on PyVis

Tags: python, graph, data-visualization, networkx, pyvis

I'm trying to plot an oriented graph with pyvis. In the documentation they suggest using the following command for creating an oriented edge:

```
net.add_edge(4,1,from=1,to=4)
```

The problems are two:

1. I'm getting this error

> TypeError: add_edge() got multiple values for argument 'to'

2. **from** is a python keyword so it can't be used as a parameter.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't need to directly specify `to` and `from` in your `add_edge` function if you had specified `directed=True` when you created your network. The order of the nodes in the `add_edge` function is enough to describe the direction.
Below is an example:

```py
from pyvis.network import Network

net = Network(directed =True)
net.add_node(0, label='a')
net.add_node(1, label='b')
net.add_edge(0,1)
net.show('mygraph.html')
```

And the output gives:

[image]